# Uniquess of LS estimator and meaning of $\textbf{P}$ in the parametric function?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression

I'm going through Rao's [Linear statistical inference and its application](http://www.ru.ac.bd/stat/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2019/03/303_10_Rao_Linear-statistical-inference-and-its-applications.pdf). On page 223, Rao states

> ... (the minimum of sum of square)  is attained  at $\pmb{\beta} = \widehat{\pmb{\beta}}$ and is $\textbf{unique}$ for all solutions $\widehat{\pmb{\beta}}$ (that satisfying the normal equation). A least squares estimator of the parametric function $\textbf{P}'\pmb{\beta}$ is defined to be
> $\textbf{P}'\widehat{\pmb{\beta}}$ where $\widehat{\pmb{\beta}}$ is any solution of the normal equation.

My questions here are:

1. I'm confused about what the meaning of uniqueness here. Seems the LS estimator is not necessarily to be unique when the matrix $\textbf{X}$ is singular.
2. Is the $\textbf{P}$ here referring to the vector of $\textbf{X}$ (i.e like a single observation) in the model? It is really confusing to me in the following argument on the same page at point (i).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is addressed at the top of page 223, it is stated that the observational equation $Y=X\beta$ is not consistent in general, but the normal equations $X^TX \beta = X^T Y$ always admit a solution, i.e. there is always some $\beta$ such that the normal equation is satisfied.

1. They are not claiming that $\hat{\beta}$ is unique, they are claiming that the minimum value of the function $f(\beta) = (Y-X\beta)^T (Y-X\beta)$ is uniquely given by $f(\hat{\beta})$ where $\hat{\beta}$ is any solution to the normal equations.
2. P here is a fixed matrix (a constant matrix), and the idea is to estimate $P^T\beta$ by $P^T \hat{\beta}$ where $\hat{\beta}$ is any solution to the normal equation. In other words, we use the plug-in estimator.

Comment: Better now, thanks a lot. I'm still confused why we care about $P^T\beta$ instead of $\beta$ itself since $\beta$ is what we are trying to estimate. Could you please explain more about it? Appreciate

Comment: @OwenTong well $P^T \beta$ is more general since if we take $P$ to be the identity, any statements made about $P^T \beta$ also hold for estimation of $\beta$ only. So the statements in the book count for both $\beta$ estimation only, but also in cases where we want to estimate some linear function of $\beta$, i.e. $P^T \beta$.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems I over thought about it.